# Angularjs: initiating first tab as active on page load

Tags: angularjs, servicenow, bootstrap-tabs

We are creating a tabs widget in ServiceNow and want to initiate the first tab as the active tab when the page loads.  Right now when the page loads, this is what we see:

[image]

We actually want to see this on load:

[image]

Our code looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li ng-click="c.activateClass(tabs)" ng-repeat="tabs in c.data.tab_labels track by $index" ng-class="{'active':tabs.active}">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{tabs}}">{{tabs}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content" >
      <div ng-repeat="content in c.data.tab_labels" id="{{content}}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>{{content}}</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    function($scope) {
      /* widget controller */
      var c = this;

        c.data.tab_labels = c.options.tab_labels.split(',');

        c.activateClass = function(subModule){
      subModule.active = !subModule.active;
    }

        console.log('tabs');
        console.log($scope);
    }
```

We tried to use ng-init, but it was returning a console error.  Any idea how to initiate the first tab on page load?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the active tab as active like this:

```
if(c.data.tab_labels.length > 0) {
    c.data.tab_labels[0].active = true;
}
```

and show the active content:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in c.data.tab_labels | filter:{active:true}">
```

Comment: thanks Bill!  when I tried your approach, the content div doesn't show up.